# How can I rename a subnet in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-vpc

Is there a way to rename a subnet in gcp? either in console or with terraform.

I rather not drop and recreate the subnet as there are other resources using the subnet.

According to Google docs, you can't change the subnet name once it is created.

Example:

```
Change subnet name = sn-env-north-01

to this = sn-dev-north-01
```

thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a way around this is to: get all dependencies of the current subnet, drop the subnet and recreate a new subnet and link all the resources back to the new subnet. Is there a script that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you've already answered your question - it's not possible.

Accordingly to the documentation [Using VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) section [Working with subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#subnet-rules):

> **You cannot change the name** or region **of a subnet after you have created it**. However, you can delete a subnet and replace it, as long
> as no resources are using it.

You can try to change this behaviour by filling a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).